# Parameterized Vertx @BeforeClass should have no parameters

Tags: junit, vert.x, parameterized

I'm trying implement a parameterized vertx test with JUnit4.

When using the following code:

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class) 
@Parameterized.UseParametersRunnerFactory(
VertxUnitRunnerWithParametersFactory.class)
public class RouteTest {

/**
 * @return the test routes
 */
@Parameters
public static Iterable<String> routes() {
    return Arrays.asList(
    "route1",
    "route2"
    );
}

@Parameter
public String route;

private static Vertx vertx;
private static File dataDir;
private static KafkaCluster kafkaCluster;
private static String URL = "localhost";
private static final int KAFKA_PORT = 9092;
private static final int ZOOKEEPER_PORT = 2181; 


@BeforeClass
public static void setUp(TestContext context) throws Exception {
    vertx = Vertx.vertx();
    setUpKafka(context);
    setUpWebService(context);
}

@AfterClass
public static void tearDownClass(TestContext context){
    vertx.close(context.asyncAssertSuccess(v -> kafkaCluster.shutdown()));
}

public static void setUpWebService(TestContext context) {
    vertx.deployVerticle("com.web.WebServiceVerticle", context.asyncAssertSuccess());
}

public static void setUpKafka(TestContext ctx) {
    Path registryPath = Paths.get(System.getenv("APP_HOME"), "kafka_cluster");
    dataDir = registryPath.toAbsolutePath().toFile();
    kafkaCluster = new KafkaCluster()
            .usingDirectory(dataDir)
            .withPorts(ZOOKEEPER_PORT, KAFKA_PORT)
            .deleteDataPriorToStartup(true)
            .deleteDataUponShutdown(true)
            .addBrokers(1);
    try {
        kafkaCluster.startup();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        ctx.fail(e);
    }
}

private HttpClient getHttpClient() {
    HttpClientOptions options = new HttpClientOptions();
    options.setTryUseCompression(true);
    options.setDefaultHost(URL);
    options.setDefaultPort(PORT);
    return vertx.createHttpClient(options);
}

@Test
public void testUnauthorized(TestContext ctx) {
    Async async = ctx.async();
    getHttpClient().get(route, res -> {
        ctx.assertEquals(401, res.statusCode());
        async.complete();
    }).end();
}
```

I get the following output:

```
java.lang.Exception: Method setUp should have no parameters
```

and

```
java.lang.Exception: Method tearDownClass should have no parameters
```

The expected behaviour for me was the behaviour I encounter when using `@RunWith(VertxUnitRunner.class)`. Here both `setUp` and `tearDown`are automatically supplied with a `TestContext`. I don't know of any way to manually create a `TestContext` Object.

Redeploying the verticle every test by using `@Before` is not an option as the real set of parameters is quite large.

I already considered adding a flag with `@Before` to ensure the verticle is only deployed once, but I can't think of a clean way to ensure proper undeploying without `@AfterClass` annotation

How do I properly configure my test to supply `@BeforeClass` and `@AfterClass` with a `TestContext`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using vert.x 3.5.1 and JUnit 4.1.2, and also get the errors you reported for **@BeforeClass** and **@AfterClass**, but not for **@Before** and **@After**. So moving the code from  **@BeforeClass** and **@AfterClass** to **@Before** and **@After** is technically feasible, even if you don't like that approach. What is your specific concern? Is it anything other than run time/performance?

A second possibility is to use **@BeforeClass** and **@AfterClass** methods with no parameters since you are not really making much use of **TestContext** in them anyway. The **TestContext** is not essential in the call to **vertx.deployVerticle()**, and if **kafkaCluster.startup()** fails just throw the exception back to the **@BeforeClass** method. Would you lose anything with that approach? If not you could change your **@BeforeClass** and **@AfterClass** code to this:

```
@BeforeClass
public static void setUp() throws Exception {
    vertx = Vertx.vertx();
    setUpKafka();
    setUpWebService();
}

@AfterClass
public static void tearDownClass() {
    vertx.close();
    // Could also call kafkaCluster.shutdown() if necessary.
}

public static void setUpWebService() {
    vertx.deployVerticle("com.web.WebServiceVerticle");
}

public static void setUpKafka() throws IOException {
    Path registryPath = Paths.get(System.getenv("APP_HOME"), "kafka_cluster");
    dataDir = registryPath.toAbsolutePath().toFile();
    kafkaCluster = new KafkaCluster()
            .usingDirectory(dataDir)
            .withPorts(ZOOKEEPER_PORT, KAFKA_PORT)
            .deleteDataPriorToStartup(true)
            .deleteDataUponShutdown(true)
            .addBrokers(1);
    kafkaCluster.startup();
}
```

A third possibility is to adopt a completely different approach for testing,  [using a TestSuite](http://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/index.html?io/vertx/ext/unit/TestSuite.html) which allows you to specify a callback to be executed before and after the tests, with **TestContext** being available. You don't need JUnit at all. See the the specs for the **[before()](http://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/ext/unit/TestSuite.html#before-io.vertx.core.Handler-)** and **[after()](http://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/ext/unit/TestSuite.html#after-io.vertx.core.Handler-)** methods. There are also **beforeEach()** and **afterEach()** methods. [Here's sample code](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-unit/java/#_writing_a_test_suite) from Vertx's web site:

```
TestSuite suite = TestSuite.create("the_test_suite");
suite.before(context -> {
  // Test suite setup
}).test("my_test_case_1", context -> {
  // Test 1
}).test("my_test_case_2", context -> {
  // Test 2
}).test("my_test_case_3", context -> {
  // Test 3
}).after(context -> {
  // Test suite cleanup
});
```